# Cost of mysql.connector.connect and connection.cursor

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm new to Python. I have to run queries in MySQL using Python mysql driver `mysql.connector`. What I want to know is the relative costs of opening connection and getting `cursor` because I need to do this in a loop. Currently, I'm opening connection outside the loop and getting cursor inside the loop:

```
def example(self, array):
        cnx = mysql.connector.connect()

        for item in array:
            cursor = cnx.cursor()  

            query = ("dummy query")
            cursor.execute(query)

            result = cursor.fetchall()
            # do something here...

            cursor.close()

        cnx.close()
```

I want to know if `cnx.cursor()` is an expensive operation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

connection is expensive, but cursor is not. what you do is correct.